# c# Regex.IsMatch String with operators present

Tags: c#, regex

I cant seem to get this code to work

```
private void test()
{
    int success = 0;
    string strLine = "E0 Q0 V1 X4 &C1 &D1 &R1 &S0 +IFC= 2,2 &K3 +FCLASS0";
    if (Regex.IsMatch(strLine, "E6 Q1 V4 X8 &C2 &D1 &R1 &S0 +IFC= 4,4 &K4 +FCLASS2"))
            success++;
    if (Regex.IsMatch(strLine, "E0 Q0 V1 X4 &C1 &D1 &R1 &S0 +IFC= 2,2 &K3 +FCLASS0"))
            success++;
    LogMessage("Success =" + success.ToString()); // SENDS DATA TO LOG SCREEN
}

private void TESTbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     test();
}
```

17:39:29.98 - Success =0

I need to match it exactly and have tried it with a backslash "\" before the operators "+&-"etc, what is the correct method for making this become true?

Comment: Why do you use regex? Why not checking `strLine == "E6 Q1 V4 X8 &C2 &D1 &R1 &S0 +IFC= 4,4 &K4 +FCLASS2"`?

Comment: or `strLine.IndexOf("E6 Q1 V4 X8 &C2 &D1 &R1 &S0 +IFC= 4,4 &K4 +FCLASS2") != -1`

Comment: How many backslashes did you use?

Comment: @choz He want to _match it exactly_. I'm not sure that `IndexOf` will help because it looks for an occurance of that string. But the regex that he tried does also look only for an occurrance not for exact match.

Comment: You'll need to use `\\+` etc.

Comment: @Verarind Oh true, he should've used `^$` in his regex then.. I mean that I don't recommend regex either for this operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on using *regular expressions* you have to *escape* key symbols (`+`, `*` etc.):

```
  String toFind = "E0 Q0 V1 X4 &C1 &D1 &R1 &S0 +IFC= 2,2 &K3 +FCLASS0";
  // String = Regex.Escape(toFind); // for "contains"
  String pattern = "^" + Regex.Escape(toFind) + "$"; // ^ ... $ for exact match 

  if (Regex.IsMatch(strLine, pattern))
    success++;
```

However, it seems that you can just *compare* strings:

```
  String toFind = "E0 Q0 V1 X4 &C1 &D1 &R1 &S0 +IFC= 2,2 &K3 +FCLASS0";

  // Exact match
  if (String.Equals(strLine, toFind, StringComparison.Ordinal))
     success++;

  // Contains
  // if (strLine.Contains(toFind)) 
  //   success++;
```

Comment: Thanks Dimity I have found that your first method works the best, as the second method requires only the string to be present.